# Valedictions: "My thoughts go your way,"

Tags: valediction

Is the valediction "My thoughts go your way," common anywhere among native English speakers? Is this phrase used differently? Do you care to comment on its connotations? Are "My thoughts are going your way," or other variations more common?

Comment: It sounds like a word for word translation from another language, but it is not a usual formula in English.

Comment: *Thinking of you*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a native English speaker, and I have never encountered it. Maybe that is because I'm a Brit. "My thoughts are/will be with you" is far more common with us.

To my mind, your thoughts going my way sounds more like philosophical agreement than sympathy. Valediction, you said: no way, it's just not British.

Comment: We say  "My thoughts *are with you*" in AmE too..

Comment: Yes we do...but we can "send best wishes your way" from a distance. I guess thoughts must travel instantaneously, but wishes take time to travel? Weird. So it goes.

Comment: @Brian. "Sending wishes your way" might only work if the wishes have onboard terminal guidance.

Comment: Yeah, it might be better to send them **to** the intended recipient, rather than just wafting them in that general direction.

Comment: *My thoughts go with you* is also common, and at least comradely. If my thoughts are merely going your way, it suggests convenience at best (fare splitting, the ability to order a cheaper and more varied dinner for two at old-style Chinese restaurants, that sort of thing), remaining free to leave the Fellowship when it passes close to Gondor.